# How to reciev a metric id in vuex getter and returns a metric name?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In vuex important to avoid vuex getters which return objects. It's better to have a vuex getter which returns an metric name for an id than it is to have a vuex getter which returns an object containing metric names and ids.

Also, when using vuex,  the primitive types are preferred objects. Ideally the getter receives a metric id and returns a metric name.

But i passing a reference to a vuex object and that isnt great since others can mutate it. its safer to use an interface than to pass a complex type.

**Please help me how to implement idea what i describe above ?**

Here I watching of the metrics that change, and if the condition works, I transfer metric objects with the key - i'ts metric id and value - metric name 
to store mutations

```
watch: {
    metric() {
        if (this.metric) {
            this.setSingleMetricNamesMap({ [this.metric.id]: this.metric.name })
        }
    }
},
```

state:

```
singleMetricNamesMap: []
```

state mutations where i push object with key: metric id and value: mantric name to state

```
        setSingleMetricNamesMap: (state, val) => {
        state.singleMetricNamesMap.push(val)
    },
```

state getters return  array with metrics

```
 singleMetricNamesMap: state => state.singleMetricNamesMap
```

Component where i call state getter then extract metric names by metric id  and bind that in html

```
        showMetricName() {
        let names = []
        if (this.singleMetricNamesMap.length > 0) {
            const findNames = this.singleMetricNamesMap.find(el => el[this.value.metricId])
            if (findNames) {
                names = findNames[this.value.metricId]
            }
        }
        return names
    }
        <z-dash-tile-config-option
        label="Metric"
        :value="showMetricName"
    >
```

Comment: Wondering where you read to avoid vuex getters which return objects? Even on there own examples they return objects: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: BTW also look at https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html if you're afraid that vuex objects in are manipulated outside vuex